# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes RC4 Child Routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

A demo application to implement Child Routes in Angular App

Angular 2 App showing Error

```
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'movie-home'
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes: 'movie-home' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes: 'movie-home'(…)
```

Application is working fine if I don't add these lines of code from file **movie.routes.ts**

```
{
    path:'movie-home',
    component:HomeComponent,
    //Remove this block of code- Start
    children:[
        {path : 'animation' , component:AnimationComponent},
        {path : 'action' , component:ActionComponent}
    ]**
    //Remove this block of code.- End
}
```

I have pushed code on GITHUB
To Clone -- https://github.com/Sandeep3005/Angular101.git
To View  -- https://github.com/Sandeep3005/Angular101
Files Structure is 
app
   |--app.component.ts
   |--app.routes.ts
   |--main.ts
   |--MovieCenter
                |--home.component.ts
                |--movie.routes.ts
                |--Action
                      |--action.component.ts
                |--Animation
                      |--animation.component.ts

Files are below
**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';
import { MovieRoutes } from './MovieCenter/movie.routes';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
 ...MovieRoutes,
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes),
];
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent,[
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**MovieCenter/home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES }  from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    template:`
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background:#8FDF98;height:100%">
        <br><br><br>
        <a [routerLink]="['/movie-home']" >Home Component</a><br>
        <a [routerLink]="['/animation']" >Animation Component</a><br>
        <a [routerLink]="['/action']" >Action Component</a>
     </div>   
    <div class="col-md-9">
        Child Component Display Section
        <hr>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </div>
    `,
    directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class HomeComponent{
}
```

**MovieCenter/movie.routes.ts**

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { AnimationComponent } from './Animation/animation.component';
import { ActionComponent } from './Action/action.component';

export const MovieRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path : '',
        redirectTo:'/movie-home',
        pathMatch : 'full'
    },
    {
        path:'movie-home',
        component:HomeComponent,
        children:[
            {path : 'animation' , component:AnimationComponent},
            {path : 'action' , component:ActionComponent}
        ]
    }
]
```

There are other files 
MovieCenter/Action/action.component.ts
MovieCenter/Animation/animation.component.ts

both files are a simple component with the template showing the name of the component

template : `Action Component`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When your Route configuration is set to below

```
{
  path:'movie-home',
  component:HomeComponent
}
```

There is only one route that Angular interprets and that is `movie-home` and hence everything works fine

Now when you change your config to this

```
{
  path:'movie-home',
  component:HomeComponent,
  children:[
    {path : 'animation' , component:AnimationComponent},
    {path : 'action' , component:ActionComponent}
  ]
}
```

Angular now knows of only two routes ie. `movie-home/animation` and 'movie-home/action'. There is no `movie-home` route because you don't have pathless route in children.
Following config should fix your issue

```
{
  path:'movie-home',
  children:[
    {path : '' , component:HomeComponent},
    {path : 'animation' , component:AnimationComponent},
    {path : 'action' , component:ActionComponent}
  ]
}
```

Make sure you are on **beta.2** version or above when it releases of **router v3**

For more details refer to http://victorsavkin.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes

Comment: yes, this is the issue ... problem solved if I change my [routerLink]=['/movie-home/action']  but if I add new path as you mention problem persist... let me dig some more and get back to you

Comment: Yeah Siraj , there was another issue not related problem solve now I more query though-----Warning in console -----'HomeComponent' not found in precompile array.  To ensure all components referred to by the RouterConfig are compiled, you must add 'HomeComponent' to the 'precompile' array of your application component. This will be required in a future release of the router.      how to get rid of this

Comment: I had told you explicitly in the answer, move to beta.2

Comment: betav2 of what I am using rc.4 version of Angular 2

Comment: Make sure you are on beta.2 version or above when it releases of router v3. This is what I said in the answer above. Hope it's clear now. Cheers :-)

Comment: With this solution you might also want to add a MovieHomeWrapper component where you can place the <router-outlet> from HomeComponent. Otherwise the components will be loaded in the <router-outlet> in the my-app component.